# AngularJS - how to use a route with dynamic data for template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm not sure what I'm fully after really hence this could easily be a duplicate of another topic - if so please direct me :)

Anyway, what I want to do is something like a shopping page, where there is a page listing out all the items. This part I can do fine :)

The issue I have is I only want one page which "details" each item - as they all share the same layout. So in this case, depending on what's selected, it routes to a details page (maybe with corresponding ID of some sort) that displays the details of whatever clicked.

Is this possible? Hope I've explained this well enough - if not please let me know.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a route for each item. You can use a route for the page itself (with `ngView`, for example) to present the details page, and then (assuming you have an object with the data) you present the current item's model appropriately.

If you can present some code I can give you a better idea.